# Как параметры из одного макроса использовать во втором?

Tags: c++, c, макросы

Есть два макроса, определённых в заголовочном файле:

```
#define FIRSTMACRO(param1, param2) void foo()

#define SECONDMACRO(param3, param4) \
    // тут чтение param1 или param2
```

Макрос `SECONDMACRO` в исходном файле вызывается и разворачивается в макросе `FIRSTMACRO`:

```
FIRSTMACRO(param1, param2)
{
    // do something
    SECONDMACRO(param3, param4)
}
```

Проблема в том, что я ограничен знаниями о том, как решить поставленную проблему, кроме как передачи `param1` или `param2` в макрос `SECONDMACRO` и последующем их чтении.

Comment: Хорошо, по сути я хочу реализовать юнит-тест. В функции, которая принимает в аргументы имя теста, по сути происходит тест какого-нибудь логического выражения. Но чтобы заполнить данные об этом тесте, я вызываю SECONDMACRO с соответствующими параметрами (например, логическое выражение и название этой проверки), чтобы он добавил эту информацию в структуру. В структуру также добавляется имя самого юнит теста, к которому как раз у меня и появилась трудность получить доступ.

Comment: Очень маленькое содержимое вашей проблемы. Напишите подробнее пример, чтобы скомпилить и исправить.

Comment: Извините, но для компиляции можно использовать данный в задании пример. В моём примере всё абсолютно то же, только изменены названия и имена параметров. Первый макрос - функция, а второй макрос - это совокупность полей структур, которым присваиваются значения, исходя из этого теста. Только вот одно поле используется для того, чтобы назвать этот тест. Например, параметр param2.